# Construct a non-constant sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let 
$$S^{n}_{r}=\bigl\{{\overline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\;:\; \|{\overline{x}}\|=r}\bigr\}$$

thn $n-$ sphere with radius $r$ where $\|{\cdot}\|$ is the usual norm in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and a point $\bar{a} \in S^n_r $. Construct a non constant sequence $ \bigl\{{\overline{x}_{k}}\bigr\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\in S^{n}_{r} $ which converges to $\bar{a}$.

---

I tried to construct the sequence on a maximum circle of a sphere.. and then inductively try to find the induction formula. I also used projections on the diameter of the circle in order to produce that formula...

But honestly I'm lost... I would like a help here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rotations and homotheties are homeomorphisms, you may suppose that $\overline{a}$ (which I will $x_0$ call $a$ because there's not needed not to lighten the notation) is equal to the point $(1,0\ldots,0)$ and that $r=1$, and note $S$ the $n$-dimensional unit sphere of $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$. Now take $u_k = \left( 1-\frac{1}{k+1}, \sqrt{1 - \left( 1-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^2}, 0, \ldots, 0 \right)$. By construction the sequence $(u_k)_k$ is in $S$, is non constant (as the first coordinate of $u_k$ is non constant, and converges to $(1,0\ldots,0)$ as $k\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you... that's easier of what I was going to do!

Comment: Np ! You have though, after an homothety, to exhibit a rotation sending your scaled initial point to $(1,0,\dots,0)$, but that is easy linear algebra.